# Arduino keeps crashing

Tags: arduino

I've got an Arduino with a WS2812 hooked up to it, powered by the USB on my computer and I am trying to run the following code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 144
#define DATA_PIN 6
#define LED_TYPE WS2812B
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.show();
}

void loop() {
  for(int dot = 0; dot < NUM_LEDS; dot++) { 
    fill_solid(leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB::Red);
    leds[dot] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[dot] = CRGB::Blue;
    FastLED.show();
    leds[dot] = CRGB::Red;
    delay(30);
  }
}

void setAll() {

  FastLED.show();
}
```

What this does is sets all the LEDs to red, then goes through each one turning it off, then to blue and then back to red.

For some reason, it gets X number of LEDs along and then crashes.  By crashes I mean the Arduino disconnects itself from the computer, but the Arduino stays on with the LED strip still powered up.

Any ideas?  This is a genuine Uno.

Also.  If I plug the LED into the 3.3v pin, the animations works just fine, but the LED flashes black and doesn't complete the Blue part.

Comment: It's not clear this is a software issue.  Isn't there an Arduino stackexchange site now?  Try there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used the NeoPixels, so I'm not really sure about this, but I'm pretty confident these will solve your problem.

First of all, your program. I don't think it is doing what you think it should do. Try with this loop, instead:

```
void loop()
{
    fill_solid(leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB::Red);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(100);


    for(int dot = 0; dot < NUM_LEDS; dot++)
    { 
        leds[dot] = CRGB::Black;
        FastLED.show();
        delay(100);

        leds[dot] = CRGB::Blue;
        FastLED.show();
        delay(100);

        leds[dot] = CRGB::Red;
        FastLED.show();
        delay(100);
    }
}
```

and remove the SetAll function, since it is useless.

Try this code with NUM_LEDS set to 5, and it should work.

Now the main problem: are you really using 144 leds powered by the USB? I suggest you to read [this link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/power) about powering the neopixels. Particularly the part stating that at full brightness each neopixel draws 60mA. Doing the math, 144 neopixels draw at most 8.64A, so you need a 5V 10A power supply to power them all! a USB with 5V 0.5A will just shut itself down when you try to turn them on, thus giving you strange behaviors.

So lower the number of leds you are using (7 at most), or use an external power supply. And by external I do not mean use the barrel jack on the arduino, but connect a 5V 10A (or more amps) to the neopixel strip, then the ground and data wire to the arduino (not the +5v) and power the arduino through the usb port: it should work.

UPDATE:

According to the chat with the author, the problem was indeed the power supply

Comment: OK - I will try this, however I am hitting an issue.  I have my 5V Breadboard PSU and have my LED power connected to the 5V+, and then my data and ground into my Arduino.  5V is going to the LEDs bu they're not lighting up.

Comment: @K20GH What is the maximum current of the breadboard PSU? Did you connect the ground of the PSU to the ground of the LEDs and the arduino? Did you send the commands to turn the leds on?

Comment: Its a 12V 3A PSU. Whilst I know this won't be enough to light the whole strip, i'd at least expect some of the LEDs to light up.   I have it wired up as follows: PSU 5v -> LED. PSU GRD -> Arduino GRD. LED GRD -> Arduino GRD.  When I do this though, the LED on my PSU goes out suggesting there is a short somewhere?

Comment: @K20GH Is it a 12V or 5V PSU? Then, since the currents are quite high, I suggest you to use thicker wires and connect the PSU ground to the LED GND directly (when you want to light up a lot of them). And... did you try to lower the number of leds you lighted up? It may be that the PSU goes in overcurrent protection, so simply shuts down the output

Comment: The plug is a 12V 3A, which goes into my breadboard PSU that steps it to 5V.  Running only 5 LEDs works fine from the Arduino, but nothing from the breadboard PSU

Comment: @K20GH if you detach the +5V from the breadboard and attach it to the +5V of the arduino does it work? If so there is a problem with the breadboard PSU. Can you send me a link of the breadboard PSU you are using? Or better the schematic, or the name of the IC it uses to get 5V

Comment: Connecting the 12V 3A PSU to the Arduino works fine, although im not sure which pin on the Arduino is 5V in?  The breadboard PSU came as part of a package, its an Elego branded one? I suspect its a version of the YwRobot one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132271/discussion-between-frarugi87-and-k20gh).

Comment: @K20GH since you solved your issue, if this answer was the right one then please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet from adafruit https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf says that you need a power supply between 6v and 7v but [USB cannot provide more than 5v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB), I am guessing the arduino crashes because it cannot find enough power.

Can you try using an external power supply?

Comment: I don't think its a power issue.  I can run any of the FastLED or NeoPixel demos absolutely fine for hours on end without any problems.
Also - the LEDs I have require 5v